# npm-bundle fails with Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

[npm-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-bundle/v/3.0.3) fails with `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'` for my NodeJs project. If I create `test.js`, `package.json` file manually and run `npm install` and then `npm-bundle` it works fine as expected. When I run `npm-bundle` for my existing project it fails. I have checked and all `node_modules`, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` exists in the project. How can I debug this issue?

```
username$npm-bundle --verbose

/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm-bundle/bin/cli.js:11
    throw error
    ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'package.json'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `package.json` the name field had `@namespace/package-name` which was causing issue, changing it to just `"name": "package-name"` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `package.json` file in the root of your project?

I find it helpful to run `npm init` when creating a new Node project instead of manually creating the `package.json` file.